# navController.navigate(R.id.tab_dashboard) messes up with bottom taps. Normal click on bottom tabs stop working

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

Facing an issue where using navController.navigate(R.id.tab_dashboard) to dynamically switch to a bottom navigation tab messes up with bottom navigation.

Attached a video to explain the issue. Video link: https://github.com/hishamMuneer/BottomNavSample/blob/master/video/bottomnav_issue.mp4
Sample code here: https://github.com/hishamMuneer/BottomNavSample.git

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        val fab = binding.fab
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_dashboard)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to understand why calling navController.navigate(R.id.tab_dashboard) is messing up with the normal tap on the on tabs.

Disclaimer: This answer targets the demonstrations why this behavior happens [per OP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76389519/navcontroller-navigater-id-tab-dashboard-messes-up-with-bottom-taps-normal-cl#comment134717864_76390350). @Arda Kazancı thankfully already provides the answer.

---

Navigating to some `BottonNavigationView` fragment using a `NavController` action doesn't actually achieve a real `BottonNavigationView` menu item selection; instead it does a fragment transaction on the fragment placeholder, i.e., the `NavHostFragment`.

That is because the action has just abstract information to the destination fragment whether the destination fragment is a part of `BottomNavigationView`, or just a normal fragment.

So, when using the action `navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_dashBoardFragment)` will not make the  `navView.setupWithNavController(navController)` do its job, or at least will distub it.

In your shared video, after hitting the fab, and then trying to hit the unsuccessful selection Home tab, that doesn't do a true selection because the `NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener` callback returns `false` (keeping the current Dashboard tab selected instead of the Home fragment).

This can be demonstrated by using a wrapper around the `NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener` interface to log the returned value of the `onNavigationItemSelected()` callback:

Use the below custom `MyBottomNavigationView` in the activity_main.xml layout instead of the `<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`:

```
class MyBottomNavigationView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : BottomNavigationView(context, attrs) {

    override fun setOnItemSelectedListener(listener: OnItemSelectedListener?) {
        // wrapper to log the returned value of the default listener 
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListenerWrapper(listener))
    }

}
```

The wrapper interface:

```
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView

class OnItemSelectedListenerWrapper(private val listener: NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener?) :
    NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val returnedValue = listener!!.onNavigationItemSelected(item)
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onNavigationItemSelected: $returnedValue")
        return returnedValue
    }
}
```

Now catching that log by doing the exact scenario shared in your video:

```
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: true
 D  onNavigationItemSelected: false  // <<<<< Here the Home tab is hit, but it keeps on the Dashboard
```

The callback returns true (i.e., it's a successful tab selection) until hitting the fab just before the last log which returns false (which is not considered a tab selection, so keep the current tab selected) which occurs when the Home tab is hit, but the Dashboard keeps on because the fab action (`R.id.action_global_dashBoardFragment`) already disturbed the functionality of the `navView.setupWithNavController(navController)`.

The answer is to never use actions with `BottomNavigationView` fragments which are automatically managed by the `NavController` with `setupWithNavController()`, but to imitate using the tab pragmatically as demonstrated by @Arda Kazancı in order to make the automation of the `setupWithNavController()` apply:

```
binding.navView.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_dashboard
```

Comment: I appreciate your thorough explanation. It's precisely what I was looking for, so I'll accept it as the correct answer. I'll give the bounty to Arda since @Arda provided the response earlier.

Comment: Congratulations on your answer. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @ArdaKazancı Thanks so much.. You did a great job and deserve the bounty 

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below to enable dynamic transition when Fab is clicked.

```
binding.navView.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_dashboard
```

your current code causes destination to break.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `setOnItemSelectedListener` to your `BottomNavigationView` something like following should resolve the issue.

```
 binding.navView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_home)
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_dashboard)
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_notifications)
            }
        }
        true
    }
```

Comment: But this would be redundant. Clicking on the bottomnav tabs is already switching to the correct tab. I want to understand why calling navController.navigate(R.id.tab_dashboard) is messing up with the normal tap on the on tabs. Please check the video. Also this messes up with backStack queue.